# Filter / prioritize phone numbers on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, addressbook

Is it anyway possible to tag certain phone numbers on your iPhone as high priority numbers, and then filter them out to perform some actions on them?.. e.g. allowing calls from these numbers to come through even when the ringer is off.

Does Apple even provide the dev access to phone api's to allow this sort of work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No apple does not provide access to this information, therefore its not possible while still having a hope that your app will be accepted to the store.

Answer (score 0):

jailbroken+ private APIs= impossible is nothing